# Complex Analysis Sketch the image under the function $w = e^z$ of each of the following subsets of the z plane:

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

(a) $\{z \in \Bbb C: Re (z) = -2\}$

(b) $\{z \in \Bbb C: Im (z) = 5\pi\}$

(c) $\{z = x + iy : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le \pi\}$

(d) $\{z = x + iy : -2 \le x \le -1, -\pi \le y \le 4\pi\}$

(e) $\{z : Im z \ge 0\}$

I know that (a) is mapped onto a circle of radius $\frac{1}{e^2}$, and b is mapped onto a ray from the origin with argument of $\pi$ (or 5$\pi$)

For the rest of the questions, I am unsure of what to do. Any help appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)$z = -2 + iy\\
w = e^z = e^{-2} e^{iy} = e^{-2}(\cos y + i\sin y)$

$(\cos y + i\sin y)$ desribes a circle

b) $z = x + 5\pi i\\
w = (e^x)e^{5\pi i} = -e^x$
The image of $w$  is the negative real numbers

c)
$x = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$

and I will let you guess what that maps to as the limits of $x,y$ change

Comment: For c), would it be the values between the circles with center (0, 0i) and radii 1 and e?

Comment: It is a half-disk.  $0\le y \le \pi$ forces it into just the upper half of the complex plane,  And $0\ge x \ge 1$ establishes the radius.  I suggest you sketch all of the endpoints, and a few of the intermediate points and see what you get.